# Compare each elements of one dictionary to other elements of it - find the similar elements

Tags: python, dictionary, compare

EDITTED VERSION:
I have a cvs file with two columns and 16000 rows. I want to check each cell (Address) with other Addresses to find the unique ones and put them into a separated dictionary (that contains ID and Address as key and value again). My csv file is something like this and I guess it is delimiter-separated values (not sure about this part and how can I check?) this is an example how it looks.

```
    ID     Address
    111    abcd
    112    def
    122    ghi
    113    gkl
    132    mno
    123    abc
    131    lnoghi
    134    mko
    135    mnoe
    136    dfo
```

I think I need to make it as a dictionary and then call one key and its value and compare it with the rest, if it was unique then put it into a new list/dic.
will it make any problem if the identical/similar elements are repeated more than once? or not?
can you please help me with that, and if you have a better way instead of making it as a dictionary I will be happy to know.

thanks

Comment: So you mean "identical" names, not "similar" names? Please show the desired output for this example input.

Comment: write your expected output

Comment: Since the names can be the same, and ids are unique, why not just make the names keys and the ids values in the dictionary? Since a name can have multiple ids, but an id can only have one name.

Comment: yeah maybe that is the better way. I can put the identical names into a new list, but in this way I cannot find out what was the IDs that has been omitted. @TimPietzcker

Comment: Perhaps you need to think a bit more thoroughly about what your actual problem is (no mention of omitted IDs in your question, for example). Also, do you really have a CSV file (i. e. delimiter-separated values) or are your values separated by whitespace as your questions suggests?

Answer (score 1):

As @RoadRunner suggested you can do the following:
considering that you've read your csv into two lists:

```
ID = [111,112,122,113,132,123,131]
Names = ['abc','def','ghi','mno','abc','mno']

dictionary = {}
for name in Names:
    dictionary[name]= []
for i in range(len(Names)):
    dictionary[Names[i]].append(ID[i])

print dictionary
```

Comment: the names and IDs are 16000 rows in csv file, so I cannot use this I guess

Comment: Is it a matter of speed?

Comment: you are saying make these lists manually by typing them? that is why I said I cannot as it is 16000. if not could you please tell me how can I make a list of 16000 elements from a csv file in a easy way?

Comment: You do not need to type them, there are ways to read data from text or csv file into Python. Please have a look to the answer provided by @RoadRunner.

Answer (score 1):

Since their can be multiple same names, and unique ids, you can make a dictionary with names as the keys, and ids as the values. Here is an example function I wrote a while ago:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def read_file(filename):

    # create the dictionary of lists
    data = defaultdict(list)

    # read the file
    with open(filename) as file:

        # skip headers
        next(file)

        # go over each line
        for line in file.readlines():

            # split lines on whitespace
            items = line.split()

            ids, name = int(items[0]), items[1]

            # append ids with name
            data[name].append(ids)

    return data
```

Which creates a dictionary of your data:

```
>>> print(dict(read_file("yourdata.txt")))
{'mno': [132, 131], 'ghi': [122], 'def': [112], 'gkl': [113], 'abc': [111, 123]}
```

Then you could simply look up the keys(names) you want to compare for ids.

Comment: Either we have a comma-delimited file, and it makes sense to use the CSV module, or we don't, and it doesn't. This answer is somewhere in-between...